# Rearrange numpy array by indices on multiple axes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was wondering how to go about reordering numpy arrays on different axes and with two shared dimensions. For instance, say I have the following (truncated) array of shape `(3, 57, 2)`:

```
A = array([[[0.93191024, 0.15612787],
        [0.71642773, 0.56644261],
        [0.56412285, 0.53022111],
        [0.08851486, 0.16253565],
        [0.34093212, 0.41074817],
        [0.02038229, 0.03693136],
        [0.09371394, 0.06565686],
        [0.93267282, 0.21915236],
        [0.96060752, 0.07309468],
        [0.82970486, 0.59032961],
        [0.3997659 , 0.51113411],
        [0.9933917 , 0.1476475 ],
        [0.45059107, 0.98992075],
        [0.64420259, 0.99047411],
        [0.11300111, 0.15220392],
        [0.28461117, 0.63130115],
        [0.31121419, 0.62935332],
        [0.05057692, 0.22276605],
        [0.44223485, 0.47280298],
        [0.45543663, 0.53295429],
        [0.41775544, 0.90341879],
        [0.80630092, 0.42294245],
        [0.82215799, 0.78450402],
        [0.53719004, 0.56694119],
        [0.47927382, 0.55033868],
        [0.51007433, 0.27610559],
        [0.33946435, 0.97437761],
        [0.97263574, 0.07449039],
        [0.840479  , 0.84473952],
        [0.65787646, 0.91151828],
        [0.93803356, 0.35804058],
        [0.93322294, 0.38717009],
        [0.4193876 , 0.54307245],
        [0.9016539 , 0.31755714],
        [0.66398876, 0.40193374],
        [0.65885493, 0.83359592],
        [0.32875318, 0.23673417],
        [0.87984555, 0.39703699],
        [0.69733635, 0.59550783],
        [0.81226642, 0.05097729],
        [0.12092097, 0.45202225],
        [0.17937865, 0.50205434],
        [0.32294824, 0.7195445 ],
        [0.78753686, 0.69291673],
        [0.24804844, 0.30187789],
        [0.0446775 , 0.81477633],
        [0.505237  , 0.29917803],
        [0.67580571, 0.95910518],
        [0.08254148, 0.74803897],
        [0.43566526, 0.31926868],
        [0.4359975 , 0.2017858 ],
        [0.19281317, 0.31834615],
        [0.89746816, 0.05457466],
        [0.3012639 , 0.24771521],
        [0.60127988, 0.2070745 ],
        [0.01068053, 0.15385391],
        [0.36193366, 0.80346892]],

       [[0.84691843, 0.64659873],
        [0.4138493 , 0.65155583],
        [0.1952568 , 0.79107071],
        [0.44328237, 0.96547454],
        [0.25811086, 0.63944066],
        [0.85353904, 0.24630087],
        [0.02200961, 0.43702606],
        [0.51187364, 0.21604095],
        [0.80455184, 0.72895394],
        [0.56534909, 0.9832036 ],
        [0.56615037, 0.41387091],
        [0.15117167, 0.96842998],
        [0.45100418, 0.33455142],
        [0.76995385, 0.80203815],
        [0.09164816, 0.08733553],
        [0.0885783 , 0.03341749],
        [0.56167238, 0.18389973],
        [0.66844602, 0.84802942],
        [0.52667165, 0.82921114],
        [0.3668573 , 0.79127918],
        [0.83358175, 0.2357053 ],
        [0.99023907, 0.72416636],
        [0.04969955, 0.16445317],
        [0.83618043, 0.61106043],
        [0.44079159, 0.53960843],
        [0.28535309, 0.57542243],
        [0.02355444, 0.96444916],
        [0.99996202, 0.22699034],
        [0.35725371, 0.3284021 ],
        [0.24784074, 0.10957504],
        [0.68893807, 0.33428212],
        [0.19549847, 0.53242997],
        [0.37411674, 0.10671197],
        [0.38613786, 0.71247659],
        [0.58098534, 0.46313774],
        [0.94364596, 0.74239641],
        [0.94446665, 0.80260609],
        [0.15405246, 0.20687026],
        [0.06607917, 0.39675446],
        [0.49393799, 0.98976068],
        [0.90401917, 0.21254029],
        [0.39854018, 0.51468104],
        [0.57275152, 0.23703318],
        [0.28854573, 0.61574602],
        [0.33767913, 0.71972114],
        [0.29835304, 0.21042103],
        [0.53764989, 0.10600488],
        [0.93471516, 0.22275683],
        [0.46161675, 0.71566021],
        [0.60435755, 0.29129393],
        [0.93588236, 0.45631744],
        [0.68130624, 0.14505727],
        [0.26229578, 0.16338432],
        [0.61311318, 0.07904725],
        [0.42231007, 0.40815435],
        [0.18240378, 0.18156717],
        [0.32826971, 0.51764318]],

       [[0.61310538, 0.70781868],
        [0.81069552, 0.40163557],
        [0.41225382, 0.55698844],
        [0.79904472, 0.57460263],
        [0.15534107, 0.14216233],
        [0.07721588, 0.00293088],
        [0.75088213, 0.15521204],
        [0.0505958 , 0.70318609],
        [0.40682637, 0.77522382],
        [0.65678125, 0.42817843],
        [0.98454818, 0.0959132 ],
        [0.04875253, 0.33109192],
        [0.96330185, 0.01330943],
        [0.06014761, 0.90105887],
        [0.88935171, 0.82924489],
        [0.68668051, 0.92581709],
        [0.64966411, 0.33036089],
        [0.92391759, 0.13665613],
        [0.78596527, 0.01177382],
        [0.36857492, 0.97854483],
        [0.11493051, 0.63332842],
        [0.89560528, 0.24904867],
        [0.19925101, 0.78383848],
        [0.16796212, 0.86980891],
        [0.64345971, 0.87019182],
        [0.98074058, 0.66858333],
        [0.89239524, 0.68869392],
        [0.05101222, 0.06246318],
        [0.19412597, 0.58740619],
        [0.47544267, 0.66208743],
        [0.30888323, 0.03953938],
        [0.39305549, 0.24437666],
        [0.34944342, 0.94852464],
        [0.93839378, 0.30905846],
        [0.28667766, 0.18239694],
        [0.93015124, 0.23186617],
        [0.41991688, 0.6963337 ],
        [0.73953573, 0.99268293],
        [0.13625265, 0.40126139],
        [0.5658131 , 0.81199939],
        [0.34594279, 0.90360269],
        [0.95083541, 0.97844242],
        [0.13066022, 0.16431073],
        [0.31765483, 0.41965885],
        [0.99760275, 0.77221808],
        [0.64802972, 0.71946862],
        [0.35160349, 0.64195416],
        [0.03926753, 0.27586446],
        [0.98373212, 0.55210807],
        [0.76304081, 0.62046984],
        [0.75019444, 0.4965763 ],
        [0.99821063, 0.92457013],
        [0.8526248 , 0.0722389 ],
        [0.01161104, 0.36656463],
        [0.54781289, 0.32044447],
        [0.68337198, 0.20499322],
        [0.41070141, 0.72194802]]])
```

And I want to rearrange the elements at dimensions 0 and 1 with an ndarray representing indices of shape `(3, 57)`, i.e. for each row I want to rearrange the 57 entries according to each index list of 57:

```
B = array([[12,  1,  9, 10,  5,  2,  7,  8,  6, 16,  4,  0, 11, 14, 13, 22,
        21, 29,  3, 15, 28, 27, 18, 23, 34, 20, 33, 31, 25, 35, 26, 24,
        32, 30, 17, 19, 40, 36, 39, 41, 47, 43, 37, 49, 44, 46, 45, 38,
        42, 48, 50, 53, 52, 54, 51, 55, 56],
       [46, 42, 55, 52, 31, 24, 43, 48, 44, 49, 35, 51, 33, 53, 16, 41,
        10,  4,  7, 13, 22,  8, 40, 15,  5, 12,  1,  9, 25,  3, 30, 26,
         6,  0, 34, 14, 32,  2, 28, 27, 39, 11, 17, 21, 20, 19, 23, 18,
        45, 36, 50, 38, 37, 29, 47, 54, 56],
       [ 4,  1, 14, 12,  6,  8,  0, 11, 13,  7,  2,  3,  9,  5, 16, 10,
        27, 28, 20, 22, 32, 25, 15, 37, 17, 34, 24, 18, 19, 43, 39, 26,
        23, 29, 30, 47, 45, 21, 31, 33, 35, 38, 44, 46, 40, 50, 36, 48,
        49, 51, 41, 42, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56]])
```

How would I go about transforming array A by indices array B?

Comment: Can you provide a fully (minimal) reproducible example (no `...`) and the expected output

Comment: Sure, I've updated my original example by providing both arrays sliced at the 0th dimension (changed to length 3 for readability).

Answer (score 0):

If the first dimension is `3` you can use:

```
np.array([A[i, B[i]] for i in range(len(A))])
#5.13 µs ± 14.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Otherwise, for longer arrays, you should look for a more performing solution.

Comment: Have you tried `A[np.arange(3)[:,None], B]`.  This indexes `A` with a (3,1) and (3,57), which `broadcast` together.